# fsockopen returns 'bool(false)'

Tags: php, codeigniter, fsockopen

My question title seems to be same with other questions but issue is different from others.
My code:

```
        $post_string = http_build_query($params);
        $parts = parse_url($url);       
        $errno = 0;
        $errstr = "";

        $fp = fsockopen($parts['scheme'].'://' . $parts['host'], isset($parts['port']) 
                   ? $parts['port'] : 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);            
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump($fp);
```

My parts array is:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => local.abhibus.com
    [path] => /search/distanceC
)
```

can anyone please let me know what is the issue in the above code which cause to return false. Thanks in advance.

Comment: isset($parts['port']) ? $parts['port'] : 443. you don't set the port ,but you use http scheme

Comment: @ChenYunlong: Yes i found the issue. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with fsockopen function. to test in local and un-secure servers, we have to remove $parts['scheme'].'://' from fsockopen function call.

```
$fp=fsockopen($parts['host'], isset($parts['port']) 
                    ? $parts['port'] : 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [first argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php#refsect1-function.fsockopen-parameters) of [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) is `$hostname`. No scheme, no `://`. Just the hostname.

Also, you should decide the default port based on the scheme:

```
// The default HTTP port is 80
$port = 80;
if (isset($parts['port'])) {
    // A port is specified in the URL; use it
    $port = $parts['port'];
} elseif ($parts['scheme'] == 'https') {
    // No port in URL and the protocol is HTTP
    // the default port for HTTPS is 443
    $port = 443;
}

$fp = fsockopen($parts['host'], $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```